# Selected item on SelectList going back to the first Item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, user-interface

i got a list using a LINQ expression:

```
List<RegionViewModel> regionList = (from rs in db.Regions   
                                   select new RegionViewModel
                                   {
                                      RegionId = rs.RegionId,
                                      RegionName = rs.RegionName
                                   }).ToList();
```

and the data for this list are:

```
RegionId                                RegionName
1A349553-E07E-4051-8E07-0144490282BF    Bangalore
1D0DA75D-D9C6-4787-9529-4F0BC2280112    USA
4F756192-4FCE-493A-9126-556F131FDBB2    Manila
E81D6D99-D4A8-4806-8718-B8552EA90FD2    Kolkata
402C0EC4-D085-4E09-9D0F-EE72AD104A41    Delhi
1DAC67BB-F2F8-4353-9BB1-FFA4B22B439D    Global
```

i'm trying to assign the list to a viewbag with the selected item as Kolkata:

```
ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(regionList, "RegionId", "RegionName", Guid.Parse("E81D6D99-D4A8-4806-8718-B8552EA90FD2"));
```

and this is my dropdown on the View:

```
Html.DropDownList("Regions", (SelectList)ViewBag.Regions, new { @class = "dropDown-field" })
```

ISSUE:
When rendered, the dropdown will display the selected item Bangalore which is supposed to be Kolkata,

please advice what did i miss. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would lead with your `Guid` as a string, because the html will render a string and it does not know how to lead with Guid, for sample.

Change you RegionId to a string.

```
List<RegionViewModel> regionList = (from rs in db.Regions   
                                   select new RegionViewModel
                                   {
                                      RegionId = rs.RegionId.ToString(),
                                      RegionName = rs.RegionName
                                   }).ToList();

ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(regionList, "RegionId", "RegionName", "E81D6D99-D4A8-4806-8718-B8552EA90FD2");
```

When you receive the value on a post, you could parse the string to the Guid again, using `Guid.Parse`